# Search Array : array_filter vs loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am really new in PHP and need a suggestion about array search.

If I want to search for an element inside a multidimensional array, I can either use `array_filter` or I can loop through the array and see if an element matching my criteria is present.

I see both suggestion at many places. Which is faster? Below is a sample array.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 4e288306a74848.46724799
    [question] => Which city is capital of New York?
    [answers] => Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e288b637072c6.27436568 
        [answer] => New York 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e288306a74848.46724799 
        [correct] => 0 
      ) 
      [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4e288b63709a24.35955656 
        [answer] => Albany 
        [question_id_fk] => 4e288306a74848.46724799 
        [correct] => 1 
      ) 
    )
  )
)
```

I am searching like this.

```
$thisQuestion = array_filter($pollQuestions, function($q) {
  return questionId == $q["id"];
});
```

Comment: Please exactly describe what you want to do? Multidimensional arrays? `array_filter()` cannot handle them natively. You're looking for a single value inside an array? `array_filter()` is not the best way to do this because you can stop iteration when you found the value you've been looking for - `array_filter()` doesn't do that. Filter a set of values from a larger set? Most likely that `array_filter()` is faster than a hand-coded `foreach`-loop because it's a built-in function.

Comment: @Stefan Gehrig I added my sample array and code for array_filter . My point is should that be similar to doing a for loop or it can be faster ? My maximum array size is 30 .

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[Array_Filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> Iterates over each value in the input array passing them to the
> callback function. If the  callback function returns true, the current
> value from input is returned into the result array. Array keys are
> preserved.

as for me same.

Comment: This is not what OP asked.

Answer (score 29):

I know, the question is old, but I disagree with the accepted answer. I was also wondering, if there was a difference between a `foreach()` loop and the `array_filter()` function and found the following post:

http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/

Levi Jackson did a nice job and compared the speed of several loop and `array_*()` functions. According to him a `foreach()` loop is faster than the `array_filter()` function. Although it mostly doesn't make such a big difference, it starts to matter, when you have to process a lot of data.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a link to an answer? If the latter, it's off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link!

Comment: Summary of the results that Levi Jackson posted at the link comparing for, foreach, while, and array_filter (foreach is fastest): foreach: 0.37 | while: 0.58 | for: 0.61 | array_filter: 0.74

Answer (score 15):

I've made a test script because I was a little skeptical ...how can an internal function be slower than a loop...

But actually it's true. Another interesting result is that php 7.4 is almost 10x faster than 7.2!

You can try yourself

```
<?php
/*** Results on my machine ***
php 7.2
array_filter: 2.5147440433502
foreach: 0.13733291625977
for i: 0.24090600013733

php 7.4
array_filter: 0.057109117507935
foreach: 0.021071910858154
for i: 0.027867078781128

php 8.2
array_filter: 0.069692134857178
foreach: 0.018320083618164
for i: 0.019519329071045
**/

ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
$data = range(0, 1000000);

// ARRAY FILTER
$start = microtime(true);
$newData = array_filter($data, function ($item) {
    return $item % 2;
});
$end = microtime(true);

echo "array_filter: ";
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;

// FOREACH
$start = microtime(true);
$newData = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item % 2) {
        $newData[] = $item;
    }
}
$end = microtime(true);

echo "foreach: ";
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;

// FOR
$start = microtime(true);
$newData = array();
$numItems = count($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i++) {
    if ($data[$i] % 2) {
        $newData[] = $data[$i];
    }
}
$end = microtime(true);

echo "for i: ";
echo $end - $start . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer these days.

Comment: when it comes to dealing with a lot of calculation this would be a very acceptable answer. A few nanoseconds can matter!

Comment: As of PHP8.2 this still seems to be the case (https://3v4l.org/Zit6P)

Comment: I've added a benchmark for 8.2, thanks @rrr

Comment: I agree with @kaiserkiwi. Results for 8.2 is a good addition

Answer (score 7):

I know it's an old question, but I'll give my two cents: for me, using a foreach loop was much faster than using array_filter. Using foreach, it took 1.4 seconds to perform a search by id, and using the filter it took 8.6 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience, `foreach` is faster. I think it has something to do with function call overhead, arguments check, copy to variable return instruction, etc.. When using a basic syntax, the parsed code is more likely to be closer to the compiled/interpreted bytecodes, have better optimization down the core.

The common rule is : anything is simplier, run faster (imply less check, less functionnality, as long as it has all you need)